# Building CMake for Windows from source by bootstrapping on Linux, then cross-compiling

Tags: windows, cmake

[CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) is a build system, but Windows binaries provided by the official project are neither code-signed nor signed with PGP.

So if you are like me and distrust the prebuilt binaries you may find the answer below useful.

I ran into a number of issues on the path to my CMake build for Windows, so the answer below may spare you some trial and error or generally repeating some steps.

---

Last time I checked the MinGW distribution was not signed either and aside from that it appears to be rather sluggish compared to GCC on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: [revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31711931/2) explains the steps for CMake 3.3.0, in case you happen to be interested in an older version of CMake.

---

In order to build CMake, we need a working CMake of some kind. Catch 22, right, since we can't trust the binaries provided on the official download page.

This answer describes how to build a Windows (32-bit, i.e. x86) build for CMake from Linux with a Linux CMake bootstrapped from the source code in order to bootstrap the Windows one.

## Building CMake `v3.12.3` for Windows via bootstrapped Linux CMake from Git

The repository is now [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Help/dev/README.rst).

### Our build system

In my case I chose Ubuntu 18.04 as the build system for bootstrapping a Windows CMake.

I assume that the meta-package `build-essential` is already installed, if not go ahead and install it. It contains *most* of the build tools we'll need.

If you don't have `qt4-qmake` installed you will get the following lines at the end of the output when invoking `./bootstrap`. This is not fatal for the first step, apparently in the same way that a missing `curses` library is non-fatal.

```
qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake': No such file or directory
qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake': No such file or directory
```

The cross-compile for Windows 32-bit will, however, fail with those exact two lines.

#### Install prerequisites

**Note (again):** it is assumed that `build-essential` is installed. So we'll want to install five packages and their dependencies:

- `mingw-w64` (required as a cross-compiler to target Windows)
- `git` (required to fetch the source from Kitware)
- `qt4-qmake` **and** `qt4-default` (required during the cross-compile)
- `nsis` (required *if* we want to run `make package` after the cross-compile)

Install these packages as follows, adjust to your package manager if you are not on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install mingw-w64 git qt4-qmake qt4-default nsis
```

### Getting the source

I'm assuming that you are inside of your home folder, but it's not mandatory. Make sure to adjust path names accordingly, though.

```
git clone https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake.git
```

This should clone the repository into a subfolder `cmake`.

### Building CMake for Linux (optional)

**NB:** Feel free to skip this step if your package manager provides a recent enough version of CMake that is suitable for the subsequent steps.

Change into it:

```
cd cmake
```

and check out the tag for the desired version (list the tags with `git tag -l`):

```
git checkout v3.12.3
```

#### Bootstrapping a Linux CMake

Follow the steps outlined on [Installing CMake](https://www.cmake.org/install/):

```
./bootstrap
```

(assuming you are still in the subfolder into which you changed in the previous section).

The process will hopefully finish successfully with the last two lines being something like:

```
---------------------------------------------
CMake has bootstrapped.  Now run make.
```

So follow the instruction and invoke `make`:

```
make
```

This should now build the actual Linux CMake which we will then use to build the Windows one.

After the `make` process finished, you should have the executables that comprise CMake under `bin`, try the `cmake` binary to see whether it works:

```
$ bin/cmake --version
cmake version 3.12.3

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

Excellent.

### Preparations for the Windows build

Now change one folder up again:

```
cd ..
```

and clone the Git repository from before into a new directory named `cmake-windows`:

```
git clone cmake cmake-windows
```

then change into that directory and check out the same tag you picked before for Linux already (or the latest stable or whatever you please, really):

```
cd cmake-windows
git checkout v3.12.3
```

### Building the Windows version of CMake

If you're curious, check out [revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31711931/2). It details an issue I ran into the first time around. Basically the built binaries were not able to run on Windows, which required that they be statically linked against certain libraries. These instructions already take care of that for you, though!

Still inside the `cmake-windows` we will now build the **Windows version** of CMake. For this we need to create a "toolchain file" `~/mingw-w64-toolchain.cmake` as outlined [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/CrossCompiling). Create a file with the following contents:

```
# the name of the target operating system
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)

# which compilers to use for C and C++
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-posix)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER i686-w64-mingw32-g++-posix)
SET(CMAKE_RC_COMPILER i686-w64-mingw32-windres)

# here is the target environment located
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH  /usr/share/mingw-w64 /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/ )

# adjust the default behaviour of the FIND_XXX() commands:
# search headers and libraries in the target environment, search
# programs in the host environment
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -static -lwinpthread" )
```

and then invoke the Linux `cmake` binary we built before (adjust the path if you didn't use your home folder as base folder):

```
~/cmake/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=~/mingw-w64-toolchain.cmake -DKWSYS_LFS_WORKS=0
```

This should create the `Makefile` which we can then use to build the Windows version.

and then run (or `make -j 8`):

```
make
```

followed by the following command to create a setup package:

```
make package
```

### The results

The result should be (with the variable expanded):

```
CPack: - package: $HOME/cmake/cmake-3.12.3-win32-x86.exe generated.
```

You should now have a CMake build which only depends on system libraries.

Last but not least copy that trusted build of CMake for Windows onto your Windows machine and use it however you please.

Including, perhaps, code-signing and making it available to the world or even bootstrapping a "native" Visual Studio build of CMake for Windows?!

Comment: I'm only through a third of it now but really awesome tutorial. Been searching high and low for a way to cross compile cmake. +1